# how to use this command npm install ws.js**

Tags: npm

I eant to make request from javascript to a web service with ws security.

SO I understand that I have to use this library

But first it's written that I should use install library

**1. First you must  install the Ws.js module: 
Collapse | Copy Code**

**npm install ws.js**

I've been searching everyehere where to use this command and how and from where to download the ws.js nut I haven

Any help is appreciated.

Thank youQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've installed node.js you can open the **node.js command promt** and install the module by using the command **npm install ws.js**